# Execute Method (that updating datagridview) from Another Form C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have 2 form. MainPage form contains datagridview and fetchTradeReport method to populate/refresh datagrid, while ColumnSettings form use to configure which datagridviewcolumn that user want to be visible or not. I have "Apply Changes" button in ColumnSettings form, and I include fetchTradeReport method in the click event. But, the datagrid still the same and don't change after I clicked it.

This is my fetchTradeReport method

```
    public void fetchTradeReport()
    {
        try
        {
            TTransport transport = new TSocket(address, port);
            TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            CacheService.Client client = new CacheService.Client(protocol);

            transport.Open();

            List<string> transactTime = new List<string>();
            SearchCriteria criteria = new SearchCriteria();
            criteria.Filters = new List<Filter>();
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

            if (Convert.ToString(tradeStatusCB.Text) != "")
                setTradeStatusFilter(criteria, (TradeReportStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(TradeReportStatus), Convert.ToString(tradeStatusCB.Text)));
            if (platformTB.Text != "")
                setPlatformFilter(criteria, platformTB.Text);
            if (exchangeTB.Text != "")
                criteria.Exchange = exchangeTB.Text;
            if (productTB.Text != "")
                criteria.Product = productTB.Text;
            if (accountTB.Text != "")
                criteria.Account = accountTB.Text;
            if (orderidTB.Text != "")
                setOrderIDFilter(criteria, orderidTB.Text);
            if (tradereportidTB.Text != "")
                setReportIDFilter(criteria, tradereportidTB.Text);
            if (tradedateDTP.Text.Length != 1)
                criteria.TradeDate = Convert.ToInt32(tradedateDTP.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

            var tradeList = client.getTradeReports(criteria);
            tradeGridView.DataSource = tradeList;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
            {
                double time = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells["TransactTime"].Value);
                string dtm = dt.AddSeconds(time).ToLocalTime().ToString();
                transactTime.Add(dtm);
            }

            tradeGridView.Columns.Remove("TransactTime");

            if(tradeGridView.Columns.Contains("TransactionTime"))
                tradeGridView.Columns.Remove("TransactionTime");

            tradeGridView.Columns.Add("TransactionTime", "TransactionTime");
            tradeGridView.Columns["TransactionTime"].ValueType = typeof(String);

            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in tradeGridView.Rows)
            {
                row.Cells["TransactionTime"].Value = transactTime[i];
                i++;
            }

            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            if (File.Exists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\\ColumnSettings.config"))
            {
                StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\\ColumnSettings.config");

                while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string columnName = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 2);
                    tradeGridView.Columns[columnName].DisplayIndex = counter;

                    if (line.Split('-').Last() == "1")
                        tradeGridView.Columns[columnName].Visible = true;
                    else
                        tradeGridView.Columns[columnName].Visible = false;

                    counter++;
                }

                readFile.Close();
            }

            else
                collectColumnName();

            transport.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

And this is how I call it in "Apply Changes" button click event in ColumnSettings form

```
    new MainPage(GetConnectionString.address, GetConnectionString.port).fetchTradeReport();
```

Sorry if my English bad. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you call `new MainPage...` you are creating a new MainPage instance, not using the existing one. The best way to solve this is creating an event in your second form, subscribing to it in your mainpage, and launching it in the second form when you want to apply changes. Have a look at [this events tutoria](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: @Pikoh Would you please show me how to code it. I'm not so good in English.